# Should I define UI default values in my service`DTO or clientside ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvvm, viewmodel, single-page-application

I have a create/edit dialog for both actions.

When I open the dialog in edit mode and do changes the selections in the UI are saved to the database.

When I open the dialog in create mode then I do not have to load ui state because I am having default values only in my UI.

1.) Now I am asking myself wether I should fetch the default values for the UI from the domain service via my DTO`s or should I define these default values for the UI in my ViewModels?

2.) What would be the advantage of each approach?

UPDATE

```
 public SchoolyearCreateRequest CreateSchoolyear()
        {
            var request = new SchoolyearCreateRequest();
            request.MaxPeriodsPerWeek = TimeTable.GetMaxPeriodsPerWeek();
            request.RotationsPerWeek = TimeTable.GetRotationsPerWeek();
            request.FirstDaysOfAWeek = TimeTable.GetFirstDaysOfAWeek();
            request.FirstDayOfWeek = TimeTable.GetFirstDaysOfAWeek().First();
            request.RotationPerWeek = TimeTable.GetRotationsPerWeek().First();
            request.MaxPeriodPerWeek = TimeTable.GetMaxPeriodsPerWeek().First();
            request.ValidStartDate = DateTime.Today;
            request.ValidEndDate = (Nullable<DateTime>)null;
            return request;
        }
```

The 3 default values (.First()) are taken from the 3 TimeTable.Get methods is this not redundant data sent to the client.

Would you still define it this way instead of inside the client side viewmodel?

**UPDATE**

```
namespace TLP.MODEL.DTO
{
    public class SchoolyearCreateRequest
    {
        public IEnumerable<DayOfWeek> FirstDaysOfAWeek { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<int> MaxPeriodsPerWeek { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<int> RotationsPerWeek { get; set; }
        public DateTime ValidStartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ValidEndDate { get; set; }
        public DayOfWeek FirstDayOfWeek { get; set; }
        public int MaxPeriodPerWeek { get; set; }
        public int RotationPerWeek { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the SchoolyearCreateRequest class, just for me to see the types to help me understand better.

Comment: @Marc yes in 8 hours when I am at home b4 my laptop :)

Comment: @Marc Done updated...

Answer (score 0):

It is not really a question of advantage/disadvantage, but of a clean separation of concerns. In my opinion, default values belong to the domain side and neither in views nor in ViewModels. Think of it this way: If you would, hypothetically take your domain services and build a completely new UI wth a non MVVMtechnology (non MVVM), your default values would still remain the same. That's quite a good indicator, they don't belong to to the UI side, as far as I can tell.

As default values are not 'real logic' either, you might consider isolating them in a config file, so that they can be changed without recompiling the software.

**UPDATE:**

Ok, got it: So what you are doing, basically: You've got a list of feasible values and you want to set an actual value in your UI (Ie: `MaxPeriodsPerWeek` == `{4, 5, 7, 3, 2}`). Your default value is the first item in the list (`4`). I agree, that there is no reason to set this default value in the domain side, as it is quite easily just the first item in a list.

It seems to me, as if you had two concepts in one class here, which makes it hard to understand what the actual purpose of your request class is. Obviously there is a set of feasible values `MaxPeriodsPerWeek` and then there is one value which represents the actually set value, 'MaxPeriodPerWeek'. Do I understand this correctly?

Without really knowing what you're trying to do, I think these two should be separated. This is what I would expect in a case that I understood you have here:

```
public class SchoolyearCreateRequest
{
    public DateTime ValidStartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ValidEndDate { get; set; }
    public DayOfWeek FirstDayOfWeek { get; set; }
    public int MaxPeriodPerWeek { get; set; }
    public int RotationPerWeek { get; set; }
}
```

Totally clear what this class and its properties mean. Your property names are really confusing: `RotationPerWeek`, `RotationsPerWeek`?? `RotationPerWeek` needs to be equal to `1` for english grammatical reasons ;)

Then define some methods in the data layer to get feasible values for your properties, if this is really required (which I doubt for DaysOfWeek and integers). Bind the `ItemsSource` of your ComboBox, or whatever you have to the feasible values, it's `SelectedValue` to your actual value and set it's initial SelectedIndex to `1` to have an initial default selection.

Hopefully, I didn't misunderstand what you're trying to do, though...

Comment: This was also my concern 'a new UI' and the logic is lost.

Comment: I  have updated my init question with a code sample. Can you say your opinion about this?

Comment: The plural values are bound to items controls. The singular values are the default value to be selected in the items controls for example :)

Comment: That's what I understood, but it shouldn't be designed that way. You dont want properties for default values on your model.

Comment: Where else do you want them? You said when the UI changes and those defaults are put there they will be lost...and I agreed.

Comment: I am not sure wether you really understood what I try to do: I have an edit/add mode in my wizard. For the add mode I have shown you my default values. But when I am in edit mode those same default variables contain the last saved values to restore the UI state when the wizard is loaded in EDIT mode.

Comment: "MaxPeriodsPerWeek and then there is one value which represents the actually set value, 'MaxPeriodPerWeek'. Do I understand this correctly?" Yes the MaxPeriods are possible values to choose from and the MaxPeriod is the saved single selection value in the database. When I load the view I have to reset the single selection value so I load it from the database... clear?